# Why does my jqueryui modal form close when I execute this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I execute this code, my jqueryui modal form closes.  Why does it do this?

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mylink').click(function(){
   $('#textfield').val = '';
 });
});`

mylink is defined like this:

`<a href"" id="mylink">My Link</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $('#textfield).val('');

That's normally how you set the value.

Comment: I tried this and the dialog still closes.  The link should only clear the text field for the user.

Comment: You're href is not good too, try href="#". And try also to return false from your click function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return false in the click function to prevent the page from posting back